# Display names in alphabetical order

Tags: c#

I was trying to make a program to have the user input 3 names and then display them in alphabetical order but I am not sure as to how to display a string this way
Any help would be appreciated

```
 string firstName, secoundName, thirdName;
        int myMoves = 1;
        int myHolder;

        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The First Name: ");
        firstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Secound Name: ");
        secoundName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Third Name: ");
        thirdName = Console.ReadLine();

        do
        {
            if()
            {

            }

        } while (myMoves > 0);
```

Comment: Have you searched StackOverflow for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having separate variables for each name, add the names to a collection type that can be natively sorted, such as a `List<string>`:

```
string[] prompts = new [] { "First", "Second", "Third" };
string tempName = null;

// Create an empty collection of strings for the names,
// starting off with a capacity equal to the number of prompts
IList<string> names = new List<string>(prompts.Length);

// Let's make the collection smarter so you don't need to repeat code
foreach (string prompt in prompts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The {0} Name: ", prompt);

    // collect the name
    tempName = Console.ReadLine();

    // check that something was entered before adding it to the list
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempName))
    {
        names.Add(tempName);
    }

    // reset the temporary name variable; probably not necessary but...
    tempName = null;
}

// Sort the list
names.Sort(); // will do a default string comparison for ordering

// Print the names
foreach (string name in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```